# Find String or String Array in a File separate them in Java

Tags: java, string, file, arraylist

I have a txt file that includes :

```
Hello Word
myStrings = [str1, str2, str3]
Goodbye Word
```

I would like to read the file to find the "myStrings" string then have a loop to check if one of the myStrings value [str1, str2, str3] match with a some variable.

Currently I am finding the myStrings like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String fileline = scanner.nextLine();
    String myStringsKey = "myStrings =";
    if(fileline.startsWith(myStringsKey)) { 

    }
}
```

How can I achieve str2 for instance to check with a defined var? I assume I should use "split".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing your string you can use the following simple method:

```
public String[] parseMyStrings(String s) {
    int beginIndex = s.indexOf("[") + 1;
    int endIndex = s.indexOf("]");

    s = s.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);

    // split and trim in one shot
    return s.split(("\\s*,\\s*"));
}
```

Then, your final code can look like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String fileline = scanner.nextLine();
    String myStringsKey = "myStrings =";
    if(fileline.startsWith(myStringsKey)) {

        String[] values = parseMyStrings(fileline);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));

    }
}
```

I think your code will be more readable and easier to extend or modify if you put the parsing logic into a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a regex and include it within the if block:

```
if (fileline.startsWith(myStringsKey)) {
    // regex to extract text within brackets
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])");  
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileline);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group().split(",")[1]); // str2
    }
}
```

Comment: but i need to check if a defined var equals str1 or str2 do we have a way to define dynamically instead of sayin [1]?

Comment: What this will return ? With which string it will compare ?Lets say this is a string "myStrings = [[st[r1, str2, str3]" and i want str3 as a output

Comment: I meant for instance i have defined static var myStatic="str3" and i have returned str1, str2, str3 between [ - ] these chars with your way. Comparison ill do between myStatic and the all other 3 strings. if i give [1] as u did ill get only str2 but i wanna find str3 or str1 according to defined one. - and in my project defined var will be dynamic ill get from user for instance.

Comment: You can loop through the array rather than accessing the index directly and then check - is that what you need?

Comment: @Mak: Once the line is split you can loop through it and check. Is that your downvote btw?

Answer (score 0):

You have to **parse** the line's contents: You should first tear out the brackets, and then split the string by commas and add every item to a `Set`, which will contain the different values.

Then, checking if that set contains your desired value is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

In a very simple way,

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String fileline = scanner.nextLine();
        String myStringsKey = "myStrings =";
        if(fileline.startsWith(myStringsKey)) { 
            String[] temp = fileline.replaceAll("myStrings =","").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").trim().split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    if(temp[i].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("str2")){
                        System.out.println("Str2 matched");
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would fail if the strings include a bracket because it will replace the brackets within each string as well. For eg: `["ab[b", "zx[ccc"]`

Comment: There are several ways to prevent them to replace such as fileline.replaceFirst("\\[", "") or substring excluding first and last char, I just show him the way to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String fileline = scanner.nextLine();
   if(fileline.contains("myStrings")) {
      String string = fileline.substring(fileline.indexOf("[") + 1, fileline.indexOf("]"));
      String[] vars = string.split(",");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vars));
   }
}
```